# Improve design of an npm module

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, module, export

I am trying to improve the design of [math.js](https://github.com/toubou91/math.js).

Concept-wise, I am trying to split a huge module into smaller ones:

[image]

When I have just a single import in `lib/index.js`, it seems to be working:

```
module.exports = require('./trigonometric')
```

But when I have a two-liner (or more),

```
module.exports = require('./trigonometric')
module.exports = require('./unit')
```

it throws a bunch of errors, as depicted in the failures below.

Every function was in a single file, but I saw this growing enormously, so, I decided that a good split between the different areas of the math functions (i.e. unit, trigonometric, etc.) would be cleaner.

[This](https://github.com/toubou91/math.js/commit/cda0d70a0501841d74692e9621e133b32a788c75) is the very first commit of this effort. I am stuck there, because I cannot resolve the imports, as you can see:

```
Failures:

  1) #math.js Testing ceil function
   Message:
     TypeError: math.ceil is not a function
   Stacktrace:
     TypeError: math.ceil is not a function
    at jasmine.Spec.<anonymous> (/Users/toubou91/git/math.js/spec/math-spec.js:9:419)

  2) #math.js Testing round function
   Message:
     TypeError: math.round is not a function
   Stacktrace:
     TypeError: math.round is not a function
    at jasmine.Spec.<anonymous> (/Users/toubou91/git/math.js/spec/math-spec.js:9:755)

  3) #math.js Testing fround function
   Message:
     TypeError: math.fround is not a function
   Stacktrace:
     TypeError: math.fround is not a function
    at jasmine.Spec.<anonymous> (/Users/toubou91/git/math.js/spec/math-spec.js:9:1104)

  4) #math.js Testing floor function
   Message:
     TypeError: math.floor is not a function
   Stacktrace:
     TypeError: math.floor is not a function
    at jasmine.Spec.<anonymous> (/Users/toubou91/git/math.js/spec/math-spec.js:9:1469)

  5) #math.js Testing random function
   Message:
     TypeError: math.random is not a function
   Stacktrace:
     TypeError: math.random is not a function
    at jasmine.Spec.<anonymous> (/Users/toubou91/git/math.js/spec/math-spec.js:9:1817)

  6) #math.js Testing sign function
   Message:
     TypeError: math.sign is not a function
   Stacktrace:
     TypeError: math.sign is not a function
    at jasmine.Spec.<anonymous> (/Users/toubou91/git/math.js/spec/math-spec.js:9:2025)

  7) #math.js Testing drop digit functions
   Message:
     TypeError: math.dropFirstDigit is not a function
   Stacktrace:
     TypeError: math.dropFirstDigit is not a function
    at jasmine.Spec.<anonymous> (/Users/toubou91/git/math.js/spec/math-spec.js:9:2366)

  8) #math.js Testing format function
   Message:
     TypeError: math.format is not a function
   Stacktrace:
     TypeError: math.format is not a function
    at jasmine.Spec.<anonymous> (/Users/toubou91/git/math.js/spec/math-spec.js:9:3022)

  9) #math.js Testing abs function
   Message:
     TypeError: math.abs is not a function
   Stacktrace:
     TypeError: math.abs is not a function
    at jasmine.Spec.<anonymous> (/Users/toubou91/git/math.js/spec/math-spec.js:9:3389)

  10) #math.js Testing array functions
   Message:
     TypeError: math.randomElement is not a function
   Stacktrace:
     TypeError: math.randomElement is not a function
    at jasmine.Spec.<anonymous> (/Users/toubou91/git/math.js/spec/math-spec.js:9:3753)

  11) #math.js Testing pow function
   Message:
     TypeError: math.pow is not a function
   Stacktrace:
     TypeError: math.pow is not a function
    at jasmine.Spec.<anonymous> (/Users/toubou91/git/math.js/spec/math-spec.js:9:4236)

  12) #math.js Testing square function
   Message:
     TypeError: math.square is not a function
   Stacktrace:
     TypeError: math.square is not a function
    at jasmine.Spec.<anonymous> (/Users/toubou91/git/math.js/spec/math-spec.js:9:4502)

  13) #math.js Testing imul function
   Message:
     TypeError: math.imul is not a function
   Stacktrace:
     TypeError: math.imul is not a function
    at jasmine.Spec.<anonymous> (/Users/toubou91/git/math.js/spec/math-spec.js:9:4770)

  14) #math.js Testing cube function
   Message:
     TypeError: math.cube is not a function
   Stacktrace:
     TypeError: math.cube is not a function
    at jasmine.Spec.<anonymous> (/Users/toubou91/git/math.js/spec/math-spec.js:9:5037)

  15) #math.js Testing sqrt function
   Message:
     TypeError: math.sqrt is not a function
   Stacktrace:
     TypeError: math.sqrt is not a function
    at jasmine.Spec.<anonymous> (/Users/toubou91/git/math.js/spec/math-spec.js:9:5299)

  16) #math.js Testing cbrt function
   Message:
     TypeError: math.cbrt is not a function
   Stacktrace:
     TypeError: math.cbrt is not a function
    at jasmine.Spec.<anonymous> (/Users/toubou91/git/math.js/spec/math-spec.js:9:5561)

  17) #math.js Testing exp function
   Message:
     TypeError: math.exp is not a function
   Stacktrace:
     TypeError: math.exp is not a function
    at jasmine.Spec.<anonymous> (/Users/toubou91/git/math.js/spec/math-spec.js:9:5825)

  18) #math.js Testing exp function
   Message:
     TypeError: math.expm1 is not a function
   Stacktrace:
     TypeError: math.expm1 is not a function
    at jasmine.Spec.<anonymous> (/Users/toubou91/git/math.js/spec/math-spec.js:9:6099)

  19) #math.js Testing between function
   Message:
     TypeError: math.between is not a function
   Stacktrace:
     TypeError: math.between is not a function
    at jasmine.Spec.<anonymous> (/Users/toubou91/git/math.js/spec/math-spec.js:9:6381)

  20) #math.js Testing trunv function
   Message:
     TypeError: math.trunc is not a function
   Stacktrace:
     TypeError: math.trunc is not a function
    at jasmine.Spec.<anonymous> (/Users/toubou91/git/math.js/spec/math-spec.js:9:6743)

  21) #math.js Testing temperature functions
   Message:
     TypeError: math.toFahrenheit is not a function
   Stacktrace:
     TypeError: math.toFahrenheit is not a function
    at jasmine.Spec.<anonymous> (/Users/toubou91/git/math.js/spec/math-spec.js:9:7097)

  22) #math.js Testing hypot function
   Message:
     TypeError: math.hypot is not a function
   Stacktrace:
     TypeError: math.hypot is not a function
    at jasmine.Spec.<anonymous> (/Users/toubou91/git/math.js/spec/math-spec.js:9:7380)

  23) #math.js Testing greatestCommonDivisor function
   Message:
     TypeError: math.greatestCommonDivisor is not a function
   Stacktrace:
     TypeError: math.greatestCommonDivisor is not a function
    at jasmine.Spec.<anonymous> (/Users/toubou91/git/math.js/spec/math-spec.js:9:7756)

  24) #math.js Testing factorial function
   Message:
     TypeError: math.factorial is not a function
   Stacktrace:
     TypeError: math.factorial is not a function
    at jasmine.Spec.<anonymous> (/Users/toubou91/git/math.js/spec/math-spec.js:9:8063)

  25) #math.js Testing prime function
   Message:
     TypeError: math.isPrime is not a function
   Stacktrace:
     TypeError: math.isPrime is not a function
    at jasmine.Spec.<anonymous> (/Users/toubou91/git/math.js/spec/math-spec.js:9:8491)

  26) #math.js Testing even function
   Message:
     TypeError: math.isEven is not a function
   Stacktrace:
     TypeError: math.isEven is not a function
    at jasmine.Spec.<anonymous> (/Users/toubou91/git/math.js/spec/math-spec.js:9:8763)

  27) #math.js Testing odd function
   Message:
     TypeError: math.isOdd is not a function
   Stacktrace:
     TypeError: math.isOdd is not a function
    at jasmine.Spec.<anonymous> (/Users/toubou91/git/math.js/spec/math-spec.js:9:9033)

  28) #math.js Common log tests
   Message:
     TypeError: math.log is not a function
   Stacktrace:
     TypeError: math.log is not a function
    at jasmine.Spec.<anonymous> (/Users/toubou91/git/math.js/spec/math-spec.js:9:9298)

  29) #math.js Common log2 tests
   Message:
     TypeError: math.log2 is not a function
   Stacktrace:
     TypeError: math.log2 is not a function
    at jasmine.Spec.<anonymous> (/Users/toubou91/git/math.js/spec/math-spec.js:9:9727)

  30) #math.js Common log10 tests
   Message:
     TypeError: math.log10 is not a function
   Stacktrace:
     TypeError: math.log10 is not a function
    at jasmine.Spec.<anonymous> (/Users/toubou91/git/math.js/spec/math-spec.js:9:10308)

  31) #math.js Common log1p tests
   Message:
     TypeError: math.log1p is not a function
   Stacktrace:
     TypeError: math.log1p is not a function
    at jasmine.Spec.<anonymous> (/Users/toubou91/git/math.js/spec/math-spec.js:9:10824)

  32) #math.js Testing unit converters
   Message:
     TypeError: math.feetToInches is not a function
   Stacktrace:
     TypeError: math.feetToInches is not a function
    at jasmine.Spec.<anonymous> (/Users/toubou91/git/math.js/spec/math-spec.js:9:11188)

  33) #math.js Testing trigonometric functions
   Message:
     TypeError: math.sin is not a function
   Stacktrace:
     TypeError: math.sin is not a function
    at jasmine.Spec.<anonymous> (/Users/toubou91/git/math.js/spec/math-spec.js:9:12715)

Finished in 0.024 seconds
33 tests, 33 assertions, 33 fai
```

I suspect that it might be because I am using the same naming (index.js) for both directories (trigonometric, unit), but still, I cannot make it work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`module.exports` is an object. When you do

```
module.exports = require('./trigonometric');
module.exports = require('./unit');
```

you first assign it the trigonometric module, then you overwrite it with the unit module. If we console.log the math object we get:

```
{ yardsToFeet: [Function: yardsToFeet],
  feetToYards: [Function: feetToYards],
  ...
  yardsToMiles: [Function: yardsToMiles],
  yardsToMeters: [Function: yardsToMeters] }
```

We can see that the trigonometric functions are missing, which is why the tests are failing.

In your dev branch you also had:

```
module.exports = [
  require('./trigonometric'),
  require('./unit')
];
```

This makes it an array that you have to use like this:

```
console.log(mathjs[0].sin(0.1));
```

Or if we console.log the math object:

```
[ { sin: [Function: sin],
    cos: [Function: cos],
    ...
    log10: [Function: log10],
    log1p: [Function: log1p] },
  { yardsToFeet: [Function: yardsToFeet],
    feetToYards: [Function: feetToYards],
    yardsToInches: [Function: yardsToInches],
    ...
    yardsToMiles: [Function: yardsToMiles],
    yardsToMeters: [Function: yardsToMeters] } ]
```

Not very user-friendly.

---

Instead you can merge the two modules together in a common object and then export that object:

```
const trig = require('./trigonometric');
const unit = require('./unit');

module.exports = Object.assign({}, trig, unit);
```

It can then be used like this: `console.log(mathjs.sin(0.1));`

You can also export two subobjects named trigonometric and unit:

```
module.exports.trigonometric = require('./trigonometric');
module.exports.unit = require('./unit');
```

It would be used like this: `console.log(mathjs.trigonometric.sin(0.1));`

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot, @MikaS ! What would you suggest as a better design choice? I would go for the first option, because it keeps my tests cleaner

Comment: @toubou I would go with the first I think. Having subobjects in the mathjs object gets too verbose. You can also put non-important functions in subobjects while having important functions in the root, if you ever get to the point where you have too many functions.

Comment: what about this? 
module.exports = Object.assign(
    require('./unit'),
    require('./trigonometric')
);

Comment: @toubou That works too, but I consider loading them on separate lines cleaner. The result should be the same though. I also changed the answer from `module.exports = Object.assign(trig, unit);` to `module.exports = Object.assign({}, trig, unit);`. Before, it copied unit into trig which it then set as the export object. Now it copies both unit and trig into an empty object, and then exports that object, which I find cleaner. The result is the same.

Comment: indeed, `module.exports = Object.assign({}, trig, unit);` is meant to be cleaner, just read the docs, but I would go for direct `require`s inside the `Object.assign` declaration. I can separate them on different lines using comma, again.